# Why am I unable to edit text in a PSD file?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I got a psd from one designer, I got the gotham font that he used but when I open the file to edit the logo and replace the current content with my own content nothing happens, another layer gets created.

If I select the original layer the fonts get selected...I noticed that there is a shape icon.
How can I work with this psd?

Please see attached picture! I use photoshop cc

[image: pic]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have there is a shape layer, not live text. There is no way to convert that shape layer back to live type.

You'll either need to reset the text or ask the original creator to NOT convert the type to a shape layer before sending it to you.

Comment: OH! thanks Scott for your quick reply, so, what do you mean when you say "reset the text" can you show me how to do that? I know zero about photoshop, I will ask the creator too but not sure if he is still available.

Comment: Exactly how you were doing it... grab the type tool, click and start typing. The change font, size, color etc. to match the shape layer.

Answer (score 0):

You have your text in rasterized format. and its not in a text layer. You should create the text newly again or it should not be converted from the shape layer